# eval string as an array

Tags: php, arrays, eval

I have a .html file which contains the following:

```
array('1', '786286', '45626');
```

That is literally all it contains.

In my code, I want to eval this and then print it:

```
$code = file_get_contents('array.html');
$nums = eval($code);
print_r($nums);
```

However, it is not printing anything.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: nevermind i'm dumb. i had to return the $code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, don't use `eval()`. it's an **EVIL** function and should be avoided like the plague.

Secondly, it's not working, because you haven't written proper PHP code. What your eval is doing is the literal equivalent of having a .php file which contains:

```
<?php
array(1,2,3)
```

There's no assignment, there's no output, and there's no `return`. There's simply an array being "executed" and then immediately being destroyed.

What you should have is

```
<?php
$arr = array(1,2,3)
```

so the array gets preserved. Which means your eval should look more like:

```
$text = file_get_contents('...');
// option 1
eval("\$arr = $text");
      ^^^^^^^
print_r($arr);

// option 2
$foo = eval("return $text");
             ^^^^^^
print_r($foo);
```